# how to open html page a massage cones up ( file:///android_assets/html/1%20html ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: android

when i want to open html page the massage comes up ( webpage at file:///android_assets/html/1%20html ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

```
public class Webhtm extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webhtm);

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        Intent data = getIntent();

        Integer page = data.getExtras().getInt("page");
                page++;

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/html/"+ page +" +html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
"file:///android_assets/html/"
```

with:

```
"file:///android_asset/html/"
```

The directory on your development machine is `assets/` (plural). The fake filesystem path for use in `WebView` is `android_asset` (singular).

<sub>and, no, I do not know why they did it that way...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

("file:///android_assets/html/"+ page +" +html");
}

With

("file:///android_asset/html/"+ page +" .html");
}